# Is a voicemail proof of intent to leave an estate to somebody?

Tags: probate

Say that person A (who owns an apartment in Miami) left a voicemail message to person B (to whom they are not related—person B would not otherwise inherit anything) saying they want to leave B everything and that he doesn't have long left to live.  Suppose that there is a logical reason for A to do so—that B had helped them when they needed help.

If person A does pass away, would a voicemail hold up in any kind of probate court?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is Florida, then a will has to be written. If there is no written will, the estate falls under the law of [intestate succession](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0700-0799/0732/0732.html), part 1. Per § 732.502, every will must be in writing, signed, and witnessed (therefore a voice mail is not a will). If there are any relatives, they may be entitled to a share; otherwise, the estate goes to the state, where it is sold and the funds go into the state school fund (§732.107).

Comment: This said, while it may not hold up in probate, it wouldn't be unusual for heirs to carry out the intent of a decedent clearly expressed through personal gifts to reflect the decedent's wishes out of moral obligation, rather than out of legal obligation. I used to do a lot of estate planning work for hospice patients and sometimes we wouldn't get it done in time, but often families would respect the decedent's expressed wishes despite their death before a will could be signed. So there may be non-legal practical end runs around the law. Oral trusts are also permitted.

Answer (score 3):

### Maybe

Rules on what is and is not a valid will vary by jurisdictions.

Many jurisdictions still use very formulaic and specific rules about what makes a will valid. For example, [Florida](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0700-0799/0732/0732.html) requires a written will, signed and with 2 qualified witness signatures. However, other jurisdictions are more liberal including allowing:

- Holographic wills (wills entirely in the testator's handwriting but without witnesses),
- Nuncupative wills (oral wills),
- Unsigned wills (including, in [queensland](/questions/tagged/queensland), an unsent [text](https://clw.com.au/is-your-text-message-a-valid-will/) message).

In a jurisdiction where the priority is to give effect to “testamentary intention”, then a voice message could be a valid will.

The relevant jurisdiction is (most likely) the place of normal residence of the testator but this can be complicated if they have more than one or die away from home.

Comment: The modern trend is to disallow nuncupative wills, or to allow them only for people who are serving in battlefields. Place of domicile is going to control, so for a FL jurisdiction, the answer is almost surely not.

Comment: @ohwilleke the asset is in Florida but the OP hasn’t clearly stated the testator is a resident